# Erro ao rodar o build p/ android - IONIC 3

Tags: android, ionic3, build

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com `Ionic 3` e quando tentei rodar o comando `ionic cordova build android`, ocorrere uma série de erros.

O console indica um problema com as variáveis de ambiente `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` e `ANDROID_HOME`. Já tentei configurá-las manualmente, mas o erro persiste. Segue a cópia do cmd:

> cordova build android
>   Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ricardo.mello\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
>   Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>   or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
>   in your path, or install Android Studio
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Comment: Instalou o Android Studio?

Comment: Não, o erro não são nas variaveis, aquilo é apenas uma sugestão, coloque o log inteiro. Se for o mesmo erro da outra pergunta então NÃO FAÇA uma nova pergunta, edite a outra. Fechamentos não são banimentos de perguntas, tem uma caixa amarela que explica o que esta de errado na pergunta, concerte-a e vote para reabrir, se o log não tiver detalhes então execute `ionic cordova build android --verbose` e copie o log na outra pergunta. Se a pergunta estiver escrita conforme os critérios de qualidade do site e o problema estiver mais claro então votarei também para reabri-la

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer funcionar adicionando os caminhos desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não, o problema não é nas variáveis, ANDROID_HOME é obsoleto (DEPRECATED), mas não parou de funcionar, tanto que mesmo sem ANDROID_SDK_ROOT o Ionic cordova compila ainda, deixei bem claro no comentário que fiz na pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416218/erro-ao-rodar-o-build-p-android-ionic-3#comment810651_416218, o autor precisa colocar o log todo, o problema dele é outro. Não é só fazer funcionar, se fosse falta de configuração nem chegaria naquele ponto do log (que esta parcial).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento okay

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar.